# How pass a List to JSP page without loading the JSP

Tags: java, hibernate, list, jsp, spring-mvc

I am using the Spring MVC framework `ModelAndView` method in controller to display a page. On the page, I have an element dropdown element and table. On selection of an option in the dropdown, I am passing the Id of the element to the controller and querying the results for the selected option. I am using Hibernate to fetch data from the db. So, the result is in the form a list of objects. I have to populate this result in the table.

The following code will display a JSP and pass a list reference to JSP. I am using that reference to populate options on the page.

Code:

```
 List<String> users = new ArrayList<String>();
 ObjectMapper objectmapper = new ObjectMapper();
 String  string = "";
 ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("xxxx");
 containerList = mapper.writeValueAsString(users);

 List<Intermediate> list = getIntermediateList();
 model.addObject("IntermediateList" , List);
 return model;
```

JSP code:

```
<td>Intermediate</td>
<td>

<select class="form-control margin" id = "dpd" >
<option value="0" selected>--Select--</option>
<c:forEach var="list" items="${IntermediateList}">
<option label="${list.name}" value="${item.id}"></option>
</c:forEach> 
 </select>
</td>
```

On select of an option from the dropdown, it will make a ajax call and pass the selected Id to the controller method:

Ajax call code:

```
$("#dpd").change(function(e){

var intermediate = $("#dpd").val();

var data = {
Intermediate : intermediate
};

$.ajax({
method : 'POST',
url : 'intermediateUsers',
data : data ,
success : function(result) {
alert("Success");
} 
,
error : function(result) {
alert('An error occurred.');
}
});
```

Controller code for querying the list:

```
@RequestMapping("/intermediateUsers")
@ResponseBody
public List<Users> intermediateUsers(@RequestParam(value = "intermediate" ,required = false) String intermediate) {

List<Users> users = null;

int selection = Integer.parseInt(intermediate);

users = service.intermediateUsers(selection);

return users;
}
```

It is working fine to this point and I am able to get the list of users based on the selected option. 
Please suggest how I may pass this list to the JSP, not by loading the entire page but by loading only the table element to populate the list. I tried many ways, like converting that list into a JSONObject, but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
function showContacts(response){
        $("#tableid tbody tr").remove();
        $.each(response.contacts, function(i, contact) {
            $("#tableid tbody").append(
                    $('<tr>').append($('<td>').text(contact.name),
                                    $('<td>').text(contact.phoneNumber),
                                    $('<td>').text(contact.address)
                                    ));
        });
    }
function loadContacts(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "url/contacts",
        success: function( response ){
            showContacts(response);
        }
    }); 
}
```